# UNIX Shell Set a Variable in a UNIX Shell Script to a Directory Path Plus File Name

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to set a variable in a `UNIX Shell` script to a directory path plus file name with a date stamp. At the command prompt this produces the results.  When I `echo FILE_DATE` back to the screen in the script is produces The name `$FILE_DATE` not the result.  I thought this would be easy. I am apparently missing something easy.

**My code:**

```
FILE_DATE=echo ls -1 /opt/ftp/receive/SSA_SSI/SSA_Accounts_*.csv | grep -oP '[\d]+[\d]+[\d]+'

echo $FILE_DATE
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are doing. But in your script you need to have `FILE_DATE=$(ls -1 ... | grep -oP '...')`. Also if you want to have `FILE_DATE` available after running your script, you should `source` it instead of executing it.

Answer (score 1):

1. The parentheses are missing around your command.
2. The `$` character also missing.
3. The `echo` command is not needed.

**Working script:**

```
FILE_DATE=$(ls -1 /opt/ftp/receive/SSA_SSI/SSA_Accounts_*.csv | grep -oP '[\d]+[\d]+[\d]+')

echo ${FILE_DATE}
```

I have created a little presentation how it works:

```
>>> ls
7093966790966902785_n.jpg  first_test.py  second_test.py  test.py
>>> MY_DATA=$(ls -1 *.py | grep "second")
>>> echo ${MY_DATA}
second_test.py
```